# I am currently in Nepal (have Nepali Visa) and looking to travel to India for a couple of days. Do I need to get an Indian visa?

Tags: visas, india, nepal

I am just wondering if a Nepal visa covers my trip to India since they are neighbouring countries.

Comment: Proximity generally has nothing to do with visa reciprocity. A Mexican visa won't give you access to the US.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you do. Nepali visa has no standing in India. Standard rules apply for your nationality, whatever they might be.